# Return to previous android version

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, device-firmware, customization

Some days ago I updated my phone to marshmallow, but after the discovery of some bugs I would return back to the previous version.
The problem is that when the phone start flashing the old android version something goes wrong and the installation aborts.
So, is it possible that this android version doesn't permit me to return back to previous ones?

Comment: You are not giving us enough information to help you, we would need to know at minimum what the device is specifically, and how/what you are flashing exactly.

Comment: If I understood your question, and if my knowledge were right, you must wipe the system partition first, because when you're trying to flash an older version, the OS checks the version, realizes it's older, and prevent it.